# passing 'generate' statement while instantiating a module in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, xilinx, hdl, synthesis

I have got a piece of verilog code, which i am trying to synthesize. There is a line in there,

```
MUX2B_XB gas34 ( notPropSig, OECin, generate, notCoutSig );
```

instantiating a module. Where, the module implements a simple Boolean logic. But, synthesizer was giving an error:

> Syntax error near "generate".

I can not understand the use of 'generate' statement in this context here while instantiation and also how to go about resolving the error without affecting the intended functionality.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be trying to use `generate` as a variable name and connect that variable to the 3rd port of your module. However, `generate` is a Verilog keyword and cannot be used as a variable name (another example would be trying to use `always` as a variable like `logic [1:0] always;`, you cannot use such keywords as variable names). You simply need to change the name of that variable:

```
logic gen; // Or whatever the type and width of this line should be
...
MUX2B_XB gas34(notPropSig, OECin, gen, notCoutSig);
```

If you actually what to use the `generate` construct for something, you'll need to provide more context so we can help.